# Background Extraction in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I am working on a project in MATLAB which will extract background from an image, like if this is an image

[image: Sample Image]

it should give me locations/coordinates of background(blue part) or person's image, so far I have calculated

1) edges using canny

2) connected component

is there any detailed work, algorithm or paper on it ? so I can do it.

**Edit**

Problem I am facing is if I detect edges, it gives me `binary` image, so if I assume that all pixels who have value `0` (black color), is my background then how would I differentiate that *I(r,c)* is the part of person or part of background ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz after you get the edges, do hole filling so you have one component representing background and another one representing foreground. If don't know which one of them is the background, then calculate, for example, the mean color for each of them in a appropriate color space and calculate the distance from each pixel in a component to this mean color. The one with lowest mean color is your background, supposedly. But separating foreground from background using this technique won't separate them very well actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is just one way to do it, but it should work.

Assuming you can make a matrix with the following values:

```
1 if it is (in the range of) your background color
0 otherwise
```

And assuming the background is only 'outside' the person (though it may still work if there is just a bit of hair around the background), then a simple way to check if something is the background would be to

1. observe the neighborhood of each pixel in the matrix
2. if the average value is high enough (say over 0.2) then assume it is a background pixel, otherwise assume it is a non-background pixel.
3. Store the result in your new matrix and you have all the locations of background pixels

So far it is quite straightforward and does not even use the fact that you already calculated the edges. Now with those edges you can make the following improvement:

If a pixel is far enough 'inside' the edges (simpler: close enough to the center of them), do not consider it a candidate for background. This should help in case someone has big blue eyes.

Comment: I want to ask how to find average value ? I mean should I use Luminance ?